# Using time.time() to time a function often return 0 seconds

Tags: python, algorithm, time, time-complexity

I have to time the implementation I did of an algorithm in one of my classes, and I am using the time.time() function to do so. After implementing it, I have to run that algorithm on a number of data files which contains small and bigger data sets in order to formally analyse its complexity.

Unfortunately, on the small data sets, I get a runtime of 0 seconds even if I get a precision of 0.000000000000000001 with that function when looking at the runtimes of the bigger data sets and I cannot believe that it really takes less than that on the smaller data sets.

My question is: Is there a problem using this function (and if so, is there another function I can use that has a better precision)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code if ever you need it:

```
import sys, time
import random

from utility import parseSystemArguments, printResults

...

def main(ville):
    start = time.time()

    solution = dynamique(ville) # Algorithm implementation

    end = time.time()

    return (end - start, solution)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.argv.insert(1, "-a")
    sys.argv.insert(2, "3")

    (algoNumber, ville, printList) = parseSystemArguments()

    (algoTime, solution) = main(ville)

    printResults(algoTime, solution, printList)
```

The printResults function:

```
def printResults(time, solution, printList=True):
    print ("Temps d'execution = " + str(time) + "s")
    if printList:
        print (solution)
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html allows you to execute the snippet multiple times.

Comment: Would I be able to get a return value from my function implementing the algorithm with timeit()? I can't see an example including that aspect in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to use the timeit module instead of the time module.

```
import timeit

...

def main(ville):
    start = timeit.default_timer()

    solution = dynamique(ville)

    end = timeit.default_timer()

    return (end - start, solution)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't confuse the resolution of the system time with the resolution of a floating point number.  The time resolution on a computer is only as frequent as the system clock is updated.  How often the system clock is updated varies from machine to machine, so to ensure that you will see a difference with time, you will need to make sure it executes for a millisecond or more.  Try putting it into a loop like this:

```
start = time.time()

k = 100000
for i in range(k)
    solution = dynamique(ville)

end = time.time()

return ((end - start)/k, solution)
```

In the final tally, you then need to divide by the number of loop iterations to know how long your code actually runs once through.  You may need to increase k to get a good measure of the execution time, or you may need to decrease it if your computer is running in the loop for a very long time.

Comment: This works, though it takes a lot longer to run as you have to run the algorithm multiple times. On the smaller data sets this is fine and removes the 0 second executions, but on the bigger data sets that take 45 seconds each, running the algorithm multiple time is too time consuming. I used the timeit module to fix my problem, as per my answer to this question. Thanks for the help though!